# Why not every real-valued continuous function on compact set can be expressed as Fourier cosine series?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series

I was reading [this notes](https://math.okstate.edu/people/lebl/uw522-s12/lec1.pdf) to learn more about Stone-Weierstrass theorem and there is a remark I do not understand:

[image]

It says that Stone-Weierstrass theorem applies but not every continuous function on $[0,\pi]$ has uniformly convergent cosine series? Isn't it contradictory?

Comment: Read the next few sentences in the notes. The point is that when you get the sequence from Stone-Weierstrass, the coefficients $a_k$ of one of the functions need not be related to the other ones, so you’re not dealing with partial sums.

Comment: This is right ^. There is a uniform limit, but the coefficients from one term in the sequence to the next need not be the same (but more terms). Moreover, the coefficients need not be the Fourier coefficients as computed via the inner product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in peek-a-boo's and Cameron Williams' comments: the incredible thing is that, apparently, the sequence of finite Fourier (or "cosine", or whatever) series that *do* converge *uniformly* to a continuous functions are *not* generally the partial sums of the Fourier series of the function (with coefficients determined by inner products...)

(The Fejer kernel (using a Cesaro summation...) approach shows the density very nicely, and illustrates that the finite Fourier series guaranteed to uniformly approach the function are *not* the finite partial sums of the Fourier series, but, rather, are some *weighted* partial sums...)

This is crazy, in my opinion! Yes. :)

As with many of these things, I guess a Baire category argument shows that this craziness is what happens generically. :)